# “The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration.” error message

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am trying to run class asp site in iis 7.5, I have verified that asp feature is turned on. I have read on other question that running aspnet_regiis.exe  will solve. But how. I run this and got information about command.

Answer (score 0):

try with add handler mapping with 
request Path = *.asp
Executable = C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll

Hope this will work